# Laravel 4 - Getting a fatal error when performing artisan:migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've just started using Laravel and I'm having trouble with artisan and migrations.

I create a migration using: `php artisan migrate:make create_clubs_table`. I am able to then create a db schema.

But when I change the schema and create a new migration using the above command I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class CreateClubsTable in /var/www/clubb/app/database/migrations/2013_10_16_202121_create_clubs_table.php on line 43
```

Now, I know it's because I now have 2 migrations with the same class name, but isn't that the idea of migrations, or am I misunderstanding the docs? Am I supposed to delete the old migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got it wrong. You shouldn't create a table twice with migrations. If you for some reason must (for example: you got one migration that drops the table after you've created it), then you can name it `recreate_clubs_table` or `create_clubs_table_again`.

If you only want to create it again and have no other migrations that alter that table after you've created it with the migration you can run it manually with `php artisan tinker --env=local` (`env` only needed if you're not in production). After you've executed the `tinker` command you can run `(new CreateClubsTable)->down();` followed by `(new CreateClubsTable)->up();`. That will run your migration for the specific class.

Comment: Thanks. I think because the migration file names were timestamped is what threw me. I thought that when I need to change the schema of a table, I create a new migration and the old migrations (and their class names) would be ignored.

So really, I should just be modifying the schema in the initial migration file, and then running `migrate:refresh`.

Comment: Ok, it makes a lot more sense now. Thanks!